# Blazor WebAssembly App - Markdig - Can not render Pipe tables or Grid tables in Markdown

Tags: c#, markdown, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have the following code in my editor:

```
@page "/editor"
@using Markdig;

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <textarea class="form-control" @bind-value="Body" @bind-value:event="oninput"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Body))
        {
            @((MarkupString)Preview)
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public string Preview => Markdown.ToHtml(Body);
}
```

It works really well with everything except tables. I have tried both pipe and grid tables that should be supported but I can't get them to render. What am I doing wrong?

https://github.com/xoofx/markdig

https://github.com/xoofx/markdig/blob/master/src/Markdig.Tests/Specs/PipeTableSpecs.md

https://github.com/xoofx/markdig/blob/master/src/Markdig.Tests/Specs/GridTableSpecs.md

Markdown:

```
# Header

Text
- List item 1
- List item 2

+---------+---------+ 
| This is | a table | 

a | b
-- | -
0 | 1
```

Pipe table works here on SO:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the docs for these tables, you'll notice that they are both referred to as *extensions*.  By default, MarkDig does not process extensions, so you'll have to enable them yourself.  The way to do that is to create and store a reference to an instance of `MarkdownPipeline`:

```
pipeline = new MarkdownPipelineBuilder().UseAdvancedExtensions().Build();
```

Then when calling `.ToHtml`, you simply pass in the pipeline as the second parameter:

```
Markdown.ToHtml(Body, pipeline);
```

How and where you decide to store this instance is up to you, of course.

Comment: Worked like a charm, used it like this: `public string Preview => Markdown.ToHtml(Body, new MarkdownPipelineBuilder().UseAdvancedExtensions().Build());`

Comment: @Ogglas, glad it worked for you.  The only reason to consider storing (caching) the pipeline would be for performance reasons.  So something to consider if that becomes an issue for you.